# Как на мобилках сделать изображение чётким?

Tags: html, css, адаптивность

Допустим есть иконка в формате png размером 100х100рх.
На десктопе нормально выглядит, а на мобилках видны пиксели, не совсем чётко выглядит.
Как сделать такую иконку чёткой на мобилках?
Можно ли улучшить качество иконки, если изначально загрузить иконку размером 200х200рх, а выводить её размером 100х100рх ?

Comment: Причина в том, что на мобильниках всё масштабируется в `window.devicePixelRatio` раз

Comment: Не знаю, поможет ли это, но есть такие сервисы, которые увеличивают разрешение картинки практически без потери качества с использованием искусственного интеллекта. Например: https://bigjpg.com/

Comment: @andreymal, а как его использовать этот `window.devicePixelRatio` ?

Comment: @Don2Quixote, этот сервис получается также увеличивает вдвое изначальное изображение.

Comment: @word это и означает увеличивать его разрешение. При масштабировании увеличенное изображение будет лучшего качество, нежели неувеличенное.